# Polymorphism with JaxRS and Jackson

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jackson, jax-rs

I have `class Admin extends User {}`. `Admin` and `User` both extends `@XmlRootElement`

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {
   ....
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Admin extends User {

    String statement;
}
```

I am sending this Json to the right JaxRS service:

```
{
    "id": "84",
    "content": "blablah",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "nicolas@robusta.io",
        "name": "Nicolas",
        "male": true,
        "admin": true,
        "statement":"hello world"
    }
}
```

Here is the Web service. The comment is supposed to have a `User`, but we have here an Admin that has a `statement` field unknown to `User`.

```
@POST
@Path("{id}/comments")
public Response createComment(@PathParam("id") long topicId, Comment comment) { ... }
```

`Comment` is not accepted as a `Comment`by Jackson because its `User` is an `Admin`:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Comment {
    String id;  
    String content;
    User user = null;
}
```

How should I tell Jackson to accept any kind of User ? How to do that the most Java EE compatible (ie with servers that have another Json handler) ?

Comment: Did you try @XmlElement(name = "user", type = Admin.class)  in Comment class

Comment: It's not always an admin. A User or Admin can create a Comment

Answer (score 2):

The jackson approach with polymorphic objects is to add some additional field in your json and use `@JsonTypeInfo` If you can change your json to something like

```
"user": {
     "type": "Admin",
     ...
 }
```

Then you can simply use

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "User", value = User.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "Admin", value = Admin.class)
})
static class User {
    public String id;
}
```

---

If you can't change your json, then things can get complicated, because there is no default way to handle such a case and you will have to write custom deserializer. And base simple case would look something like this:

```
public static class PolymorphicDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<User> {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode tree = p.readValueAsTree();

        if (tree.has("statement")) // <= hardcoded field name that Admin has
            return mapper.convertValue(tree, Admin.class);

        return mapper.convertValue(tree, User.class);

    }
}
```

You can register it on ObjectMapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(User.class, new PolymorphicDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

or with annotation:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = PolymorphicDeserializer.class)
class User {
    public String id;
}
```