# Deserialize to a default base type in Jackson java

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have two objects in the format

```
class A { 
    private static String TYPE = "A"

    @jsonProperty("p")
    private Property1 p;
}

class B { 
    private static String TYPE = "B"

    @jsonProperty("p")
    private Property2 p;
}
```

and in the json format

for A

```
{
    type: "A",
    p: {
        type: "property1",
        name: "n",
        id: "i"
    }
}
```

For B

```
{
    type: "B",
    p: {
        type: "Property2"
        name: "n",
        id: "i",
        extraProp1: "p1",
        extraProp2: "p2"
    }
 }
```

I want to deserialize to class B if that fails, deserialize to class A and ignore the unknown properties

What is the best way to do that using Jackson ?

Comment: can you create common superclass/interface for both class A and class B?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to create a super class or interface for them, but still .. how can the fallback part happen, basically the client for that library will sometimes not have class B built in the Jar and in that case I want to fall back to a default .. which is B

Comment: Well, what you could do is to create common interface and deserialize to this interface. Register custom serializer for this common interface and in this custom deserializer you can do all the logic. If json contains some string or some type => serialize to B and if it doesn't fallback to A. But you probably can do the same with `@JsonTypeInfo` https://stackoverflow.com/a/47108221/1032167